# Postgres 9.4.4 value too long for type character varying

Tags: java, postgresql, wildfly-8

When i try to login into our java application i'am getting error below. When i submit again it successfully loggedin

```
ERROR: value too long for type character varying(32) getting .
```

`Postgres9.4.4` is using in app with `java 1.6` and `wildlfy 8` as server.

Comment: Sounds like you have a bug somewhere. Nothing we can do here without you showing the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column which has current url as value makes this issue.

Change the column with `character varying(32)` to `character varying(200)` resolves the issue.

Comment: This is a bad solution. `Text` is a non-ansi type intended for very long text strings. If you want to store all of wikipedia as one, long, string, you'd use `text`.

Comment: Consider increasing the width of the varchar field instead. Perhaps `character varying(200)` would work well.